# django - how to save(update) datetime field to database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, python-datetime

I've got some problems with Django DateTimeField. I want my script to add 7 days to *expiration_date* field in database when some conditions occur.

**models.py**

```py
class TrainingPlan(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete='CASCADE')
    exercise_list = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
```

**views.py**

```py
 def check_plan_expiration_date():
    user_exp_date = user_trainingplan.expiration_date
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    if user_exp_date <= now:
        user_exp_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)+timedelta(days=7)
        user_exp_date.save()
    else:
        return user_exp_date
```

Error I get:
**'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'save'**

Answer (score 1):

Work with the model

```
def check_plan_expiration_date():

    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    if user_trainingplan.expiration_date <= now:
        user_trainingplan.expiration_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)+timedelta(days=7)
        user_trainingplan.save()
    else:
        return user_trainingplan.expiration_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `save()` method on the wrong object / variable. You want to set the new `user_exp_date` to the `user_trainingplan.expiration_date` attribute and call `user_trainingplan.save()`

```
def check_plan_expiration_date():
    user_exp_date = user_trainingplan.expiration_date
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    if user_exp_date <= now:
        user_trainingplan.expiration_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)+timedelta(days=7)
        user_trainingplan.save()
    else:
        return user_exp_date
```